# Redirection from HTTP to HTTPS (Best method is .htaccess or PHP redirection code)

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

It was required for me to redirect my websites links from http to https
After searching on google I found code to insert in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But unfortunately .htaccess file was hidden in my hosting cPanel and unable to rewrite.
So I found following PHP code for redirection from http to https (as an alternate to .htaccess)

```
// Redirection from http to https
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on") {
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

I placed above code on each page and it is redirecting perfectly.

I want to know is their any drawback of using php code instead of .htaccess for redirection from http to https.

Comment: did you click "show dotted file?" at the cpanel to see the .htaccess file? its impossible to restrict writing into it

Comment: If your code works and you just want someone to look it over and see it there's a better way, please post it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: _“I want to know is their any drawback of using php code instead of .htaccess for redirection from http to https.”_ - well for starters, it only works for resources that are served with the help of PHP in the first place … So `http://example.com/image.jpg` or `http://example.com/important_document_we_should_only_serve_over_a_secure_connection.pdf` will likely not be affected. (Whether that actually matters in the current case, not for us to say.)

Comment: With Apache, my preferred method is to do a permanent redirect in the vhost file. Dont event want to get a hit on my restful php backend , with http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution one (edit .htaccess file)**

To see the .htaccess file, try to do the following

- Go to the Cpanel
- Click file manager
- Choose hidden files
- select .htaccess file and click edit

[image]

**Solution two (use Cloudflare.com)**

use Cloudflare https redirection rule if your domain is linked to Cloudflare